# jOOQ select field datatype

Tags: java, select, converters, jooq

Is it possible in jOOQ to change field datatype when doing select?

For example I have jOOQ generated sources and there is field X and I want to change it's data type. I'm trying to add converter.

Example:

```
select(PERSON.field(PERSON.ADDRESS.getName(), addressConverter.getDataType()));
```

I can't replace table field easily. I need to remove field from table fields and then make new select (example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to "change" a field to have a new data type for a specific `SELECT` query is to use [`Field.coerce(DataType)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-org.jooq.DataType-). For example:

```
select(PERSON.ADDRESS.coerce(addressConverter.getDataType()))
.from(...)
```

If you want to retain all the other fields in the `PERSON` table, you could proceed like this:

```
select(Stream.of(PERSON.fields()).map(
     f -> f == PERSON.ADDRESS 
        ? f.coerce(addressConverter.getDataType())
        : f).toArray(Field[]::new))
.from(...)
```

Of course, you could also factor out this particular data type replacement in a dedicated function.